# create a div slideshow with controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi there ive tried to write a simple slideshow for my form as it is too long.i decided to seperate the form into four different parts absolutely positionned on top of each other.Now i want to cycle through them like a slideshow here is the css class for my divs their container is already set to position relative

```
            .feuille{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:600px;
    height:494px;
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-300px;
    margin-top:-247px;
    }
```

i have my controls with ids set to prev and next.onclick,the topmost div ,imean the one which is currently on top fades out and is immediately appended to the end.how to achieve this?

Comment: something which may help you http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php

Comment: i dont know what the problem is but all i see is a big black background when i click on the link you ve given me.anyways i achieved the effect using this $('.intern > div:last').fadeOut('slow').prependTo('.intern').fadeIn(1000);

Comment: Great.:). you can post the answer too, so in future someone save their time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the effect you're looking for?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/9JHqL/)

CSS

```
$(function(){
    $('.feuille img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.feuille :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.feuille');}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: yes actually i needed something like that i managed to do it  $('.intern >div:last').fadeOut('slow').prependTo('.intern').fadeIn(1000);.In my file the divs are on top of one another if i make the topmost one disappear the immediate bottom div will be automatically visible like in a queue thank you all for pointing me to the right path thnks